# After using Docker in my puppeteer project it is not working. Giving error

Tags: javascript, docker, docker-compose, puppeteer

Recently I'm using docker in my existing MERN project and **scraping** data using Puppeteer.It was working fine but once I used docker it is not working. Giving following errors.

```
----------- Open the browser ------------
server    | Could not create a browser instance => :  Error: Failed to launch the browser process! spawn /usr/bin/chromium-browser ENOENT
server    | 
server    | 
server    | TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
server    | 
server    |     at onClose (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:193:20)
server    |     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/node/BrowserRunner.js:185:85)
server    |     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
server    |     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:274:12)
server    |     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:468:16)
server    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
server    | ----------- Open a new page ------------
server    | Could not create a new page => :  TypeError: Cannot read property 'newPage' of undefined
server    |     at startPage (/app/controller/helper/browserHelper.js:35:26)
server    |     at businessinsiderOld (/app/controller/businessinsider/old.js:13:16)
server    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
server    | (node:33) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'goto' of undefined
server    |     at businessinsiderOld (/app/controller/businessinsider/old.js:16:14)
server    |     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
server    | (node:33) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
server    | (node:33) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my server dockerfile

```
FROM node:14.5.0
WORKDIR /app   
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: Getting headless Chrome up and running in Docker can be tricky. The bundled Chromium that Puppeteer installs is missing the necessary shared library dependencies.

To fix, you'll probably need to install the missing dependencies and the latest Chromium package in your Dockerfile - info here https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md#running-puppeteer-in-docker

Comment: it doesn't work for me. I have mentioned the answer below

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have just used the following codes and it works,

```
FROM node:14.5.0
WORKDIR /app


# Install latest chrome dev package and fonts to support major charsets (Chinese, Japanese, Arabic, Hebrew, Thai and a few others)
# Note: this installs the necessary libs to make the bundled version of Chromium that Puppeteer
# installs, work.
# https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/google_chrome/stable/main/base/google-chrome-unstable
RUN apt-get update

# for https
RUN apt-get install -yyq ca-certificates
# install libraries
RUN apt-get install -yyq libappindicator1 libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libnss3 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6
# tools
RUN apt-get install -yyq gconf-service lsb-release wget xdg-utils
# and fonts
RUN apt-get install -yyq fonts-liberation 

COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install



COPY . .
EXPOSE 9000
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

Comment: are you able to execute script in  { headless: false }  mode ?

Comment: are you able to execute script in  { headless: false }  mode ?